# Rspec says implemented method is not implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

Below is an rspec test I'm running to test another class I've made. Unfortunately the method I'm trying to test (`delete`) does not seem to be working. What's throwing me is that the error message I'm getting from the Termianl is:

`/Users/user/Ruby/localWikiClient/localwiki_client/spec/delete_spec:11:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method 'delete' for #<Proc:0x007fe4739a5448> (NoMethodError)`

However, this method is defined in the class. Below is the code:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json/pure'

module Localwiki

  ##
  # A client that wraps the localwiki api for a given server instance
  #
  class Client

    attr_accessor :hostname       # hostname of the server we'd like to point at
    attr_reader   :site_name      # site resource - display name of wiki
    attr_reader   :time_zone      # site resource - time zone of server, e.g. 'America/Chicago'
    attr_reader   :language_code  # site resource - language code of the server, e.g. 'en-us'

    def initialize hostname, user=nil, apikey=nil
      @hostname = hostname
      @user = user
      @apikey = apikey
      create_connection
      collect_site_details
    end

   ##
   # Get site resource and set instance variables
   #
   def collect_site_details
       site = fetch('site','1')
       @site_name = site['name']
       @time_zone = site['time_zone']
       @language_code = site['language_code']
   end

   ##
   # create Faraday::Connection instance and set @site
   #
   def create_connection
      @site = Faraday.new :url => @hostname
   end

   ##
   # delete a specific resource
   # resources are "site", "page", "user", "file", "map", "tag", "page_tag"
   # identifier is id, pagename, slug, etc.
  def delete(resource,identifier)
    case resource
    when resource == "site"
      @hostname = identifier
      create_connection
    when resouce == "user"
      @hostname = list(identifier)   
    end  

    http_delete()
  end

  def http_delete()
    response = @site.delete
    puts response.to_s
  end
```

Here's the rspec test I'm trying to run:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)
require 'localwiki_client'

describe '<siteinfo>.amazonaws.com/bears' do

  subject { Localwiki::Client.new '<siteinfo>.compute-1.amazonaws.com/bears', '<username>', '[myApiKey]' }

  context '#fetch' do
    subject.delete('page', 'bears')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't access the subject like that within a context block. You will need to either put it in a before block or within an actual test block (it/specify):

```
describe '<siteinfo>.amazonaws.com/bears' do

  subject { Localwiki::Client.new '<siteinfo>.compute-1.amazonaws.com/bears', '<username>', '[myApiKey]' }

  context '#fetch' do
    it "deletes the bears page" do
      subject.delete('page', 'bears')
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Sorry.. I'm brand new to Ruby, could you include an example of what you mean in your answer?

Comment: I did... notice how I wrapped the `subject.delete` line in an "it" block above.